I am not able to create a python module that correctly supports type checking
I have created a python module MyModule that is entirely written with typing support (for a matter of maintenance).
But when I write a script that uses MyModule, let's say MyScript.py:
from MyModule import MyClass, MyOtherClass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass(1, 2)
    a = MyOtherClass(90)

To run my script, I use PYTHONPATH=pathtomodule python MyScript.py and it runs fine.
But, when I run PYTHONPATH=pathtomodule mypy MyScript.py, I get the following error:
MyScript.py:1: error: Module "MyModule " has no attribute "MyClass"  [attr-defined]
MyScript.py:1: error: Module "MyModule " has no attribute "MyOtherClass"  [attr-defined]

To be complete, here is the layout of my module files:

pathtomodule/

MyModule/

py.typed : empty
__init__.py : empty
MyModule.py : contains the classes definition





I have noticed that if i add to __init__.py the following line, it will work:
from .MyModule import MyClass, MyOtherClass

but i do not understand why.  Do I need to add all the interfaces to that file to support typing in script that use my module?

Are you saying that typing is somehow causing this issue, or could it by that you want more information about how modules and init.py work?

You have a package named MyModule which contains another module named MyModule. None of this has anything to do with type checking: you're just importing the wrong module.

The reason why your script is unable to find your classes is because it is not looking in the correct place.
Your package (or folder, the main container of your modules) name is MyModule. When you attempt to import MyClass and MyOtherClass from MyModule, the folder is where you're looking, not the MyModule.py itself.
To get the classes, you need to go into the file MyModule.py inside of your package MyModule. Thus, replace your import statement with from MyModule.MyModule import MyClass, MyOtherClass.

I finally found my mistake, this is a combination of package vs module misunderstanding and wrong variable:

calling:
PYTHONPATH=pathtomodule mypy MyScript.py
instead of:
MYPYPATH=pathtomodule/MyModule mypy MyScript.py

I hope it will help others!  I had been fighting to understand if I needed to create a package with a py.typed etc... in the end, for local modules (such as mine), none of these is really necessary, just use MYPYPATH instead of the PYTHONPATH (which is the one i use to add my local modules when running a script).
But my module hierarchy is not really neat as others have explained, having a package with the same name as the module is misleading.
I ended up with the following hierarchy:

pathtomodule/

MyModule.py : contains the classes definition



and now it is much easier:

to run:
PYTHONPATH=pathtomodule python MyScript.py
to verify: MYPYPATH=pathtomodule mypy MyScript.py

and there is no more confusion between package and module.
